# Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, clang

I started to get this peculiar compiler error which I cannot seem to solve. I went through some other posts in internet suggesting fixes, but none of them worked for me. I tried changing the build settings and changed all "self.x"s to "[self x]" as suggested; but didn't help.

There is multilevel inheritance in my code, (ie game -> board game -> tictactoegame) and im guessing, that structure is the root of problems. The compiler seems to crash at viewcontroller's line of code just after it synthesizes an instance of tictactoegame named 'game'.

What is a possible mistake i'm doing? Any help would be appreciated, if you need more info to detect just tell me. This is the error log:

```
CompileC "/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToeViewController.o" "AlDente GameCenter/../TicTacToeViewController.m" normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
        cd "/Users/guvenis/Desktop/AlDente GameCenter"
        setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
        setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -iquote "/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/AlDente GameCenter-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/AlDente GameCenter-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/AlDente GameCenter-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/AlDente GameCenter-project-headers.hmap" -I/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include "-I/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/DerivedSources" -F/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include "/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/AlDente GameCenter-Prefix-fegzlqlfizxpgwaenbkzicwpltxv/AlDente GameCenter-Prefix.pch" -MMD -MT dependencies -MF "/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToeViewController.d" --serialize-diagnostics "/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToeViewController.dia" -c "/Users/guvenis/Desktop/AlDente GameCenter/AlDente GameCenter/../TicTacToeViewController.m" -o "/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToeViewController.o"

0  clang             0x000000010c381422 _ZL15PrintStackTracePv + 34
1  clang             0x000000010c3818a9 _ZL13SignalHandleri + 553
2  libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff86fb2cfa _sigtramp + 26
3  clang             0x000000010c72ec10 vtable for llvm::DIFile + 16
4  clang             0x000000010b4d736c clang::ASTContext::getTypeInfo(clang::Type const*) const + 1148
5  clang             0x000000010b4df7cc clang::ASTContext::getTypeInfoInChars(clang::QualType) const + 28
6  clang             0x000000010b4df291 (anonymous namespace)::RecordLayoutBuilder::LayoutField(clang::FieldDecl const*) + 1889
7  clang             0x000000010b5d8b1b clang::ASTContext::getObjCLayout(clang::ObjCInterfaceDecl const*, clang::ObjCImplementationDecl const*) const + 1003
8  clang             0x000000010bc30396 clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::CreateType(clang::ObjCInterfaceType const*, llvm::DIFile) + 1526
9  clang             0x000000010bc31a5c clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::CreateTypeNode(clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 332
10 clang             0x000000010bc2a259 clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::getOrCreateType(clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 489
11 clang             0x000000010bc2bdde clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::CreatePointeeType(clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 894
12 clang             0x000000010bc2b9bd clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::CreatePointerLikeType(unsigned int, clang::Type const*, clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 285
13 clang             0x000000010bc319f5 clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::CreateTypeNode(clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 229
14 clang             0x000000010bc2a259 clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::getOrCreateType(clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 489
15 clang             0x000000010bc2b7d7 clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::CreateQualifiedType(clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 183
16 clang             0x000000010bc3195e clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::CreateTypeNode(clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 78
17 clang             0x000000010bc2a259 clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::getOrCreateType(clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 489
18 clang             0x000000010bc32431 clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::getOrCreateFunctionType(clang::Decl const*, clang::QualType, llvm::DIFile) + 369
19 clang             0x000000010bc32e2a clang::CodeGen::CGDebugInfo::EmitFunctionStart(clang::GlobalDecl, clang::QualType, llvm::Function*, llvm::IRBuilder<false, llvm::ConstantFolder, llvm::IRBuilderDefaultInserter<false> >&) + 1866
20 clang             0x000000010b5ebc11 clang::CodeGen::CodeGenFunction::StartFunction(clang::GlobalDecl, clang::QualType, llvm::Function*, clang::CodeGen::CGFunctionInfo const&, clang::CodeGen::FunctionArgList const&, clang::SourceLocation) + 1073
21 clang             0x000000010bc48034 clang::CodeGen::CodeGenFunction::StartObjCMethod(clang::ObjCMethodDecl const*, clang::ObjCContainerDecl const*, clang::SourceLocation) + 548
22 clang             0x000000010bc481a6 clang::CodeGen::CodeGenFunction::GenerateObjCMethod(clang::ObjCMethodDecl const*) + 38
23 clang             0x000000010b4fe07c clang::CodeGen::CodeGenModule::EmitTopLevelDecl(clang::Decl*) + 876
24 clang             0x000000010b4fdcef (anonymous namespace)::CodeGeneratorImpl::HandleTopLevelDecl(clang::DeclGroupRef) + 95
25 clang             0x000000010b4fdc51 clang::BackendConsumer::HandleTopLevelDecl(clang::DeclGroupRef) + 161
26 clang             0x000000010b4c6092 clang::ParseAST(clang::Sema&, bool) + 306
27 clang             0x000000010b4c4bd7 clang::CodeGenAction::ExecuteAction() + 855
28 clang             0x000000010b49713f clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) + 879
29 clang             0x000000010b495dcb clang::ExecuteCompilerInvocation(clang::CompilerInstance*) + 2683
30 clang             0x000000010b4885ce cc1_main(char const**, char const**, char const*, void*) + 5086
31 clang             0x000000010b462dd8 main + 648
32 clang             0x000000010b462b44 start + 52
33 clang             0x0000000000000070 start + 18446744069225436512
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple i386-apple-macosx10.6.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name TicTacToeViewController.m -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -target-cpu yonah -target-linker-version 128.2 -g -coverage-file /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToeViewController.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.1 -dependency-file /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToeViewController.d -MT dependencies -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -iquote /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/AlDente GameCenter-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/AlDente GameCenter-project-headers.hmap -include-pch /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/AlDente GameCenter-Prefix-fegzlqlfizxpgwaenbkzicwpltxv/AlDente GameCenter-Prefix.pch.pth -D DEBUG=1 -D IBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet)) -D IBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName))) -D IBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction) -D __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -I /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/AlDente GameCenter-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/AlDente GameCenter-all-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/4f/z2kfb3mj34qfy4jczzt7txr40000gn/T/clang-module-cache -O0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -std=gnu99 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-arc -fobjc-exceptions -fexceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToeViewController.dia -o /Users/guvenis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlDente_GameCenter-gnkchngrsovmqlbsdelpoqdyohyg/Build/Intermediates/AlDente GameCenter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlDente GameCenter.build/Objects-normal/i386/TicTacToeViewController.o -x objective-c /Users/guvenis/Desktop/AlDente GameCenter/AlDente GameCenter/../TicTacToeViewController.m 
1.  <eof> parser at end of file
2.  /Users/guvenis/Desktop/AlDente GameCenter/AlDente GameCenter/../TicTacToeViewController.m:25:1: LLVM IR generation of declaration 'TicTacToeViewController::checkLastMovesScore'
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal 2 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include command line arguments and all diagnostic information.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/4f/z2kfb3mj34qfy4jczzt7txr40000gn/T/TicTacToeViewController-bttija.mi
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/4f/z2kfb3mj34qfy4jczzt7txr40000gn/T/TicTacToeViewController-bttija.sh
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an enum instance imported from the game class header in the viewcontroller, removing it fixed my problem. It compiles without errors now. Struggle for 2 hours, fix it yourself 5mins after posting it in stackoverflow.